# Связь между массивами

Tags: javascript, массивы

В функции ниже в итоге, когда n станет меньше 1, должен выводится пустой массив, как указано в условии. Но выводятся цифры в обратном порядке в массиве. Это указано в остаточном условии, но они должны помещаться в массив arr, на которой висит рекурсия. Не вижу связи между пустым массивом, который должен выводится в первом условии, и массивом arr, в который пушатся значения. Спасибо за ответ!

```js
function countdown(n){
  if(n < 1) {
      return [];
  } else {
      let arr = countdown(n -1);
      arr.unshift(n);
      return arr;
  }
}

console.log( countdown(5) );
```

Comment: Именно в этот пустой массив из глубины и добавляются все значения n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> когда n станет меньше 1, должен выводится пустой массив

Не "выводится", а "возвращаться", что и происходит. Но потом, во время движения обратно вверх по цепочке вызовов, в этот массив добавляются числа.

```js
function countdown(n) {
  let arr;
  if (n < 1) {
    arr = ['bottom'];
  } else {
    arr = countdown(n - 1);
    arr.unshift(n);
  }
  console.log(n, JSON.stringify(arr));
  return arr;
}

console.log(countdown(5));
```

Comment: В объяснении без слов что-то очевидно есть))) Осталось еще добавить адреса массивов в памяти чтобы было еще понятнее))

Comment: @Leonid Да, я после Вашего комментария к вопросу добавил в массив строку, чтобы было видно, что этот тот же массив поднимается обратно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но не совсем понял - Вы написали, что все ок, выводится пустой массив, как и должен. И что ПОТОМ в него добавляются числа. Но по идее возврат пустого объекта должен быть заключительным действием функции, разве нет? Я же правильно понимаю порядок: сначала идет наполнение массива arr, а затем уже идет возврат первого условия - пустого массива.
И в приведенном Вами коде все понятно - был объявлен массив arr, который в который добавлена строка, и в который добавляются числа, и который же возвращается, когда первое условие выполнится, связь понятна.

Comment: @Paul Нет. Проследите выполнение кода шаг за шагом для случаев `countdown(0)` и `countdown(1)`.

Comment: @Paul, рекурсивную функцию можно представить в виде дерева. Корень здесь (если изначально в функцию передается не пустой массив) - функция, вызванная из console.log. Прямой потомок - вызов `countdown(n-1)`, а самый вложенный "потомок", где `n<1` возвращает пустой массив. Этот массив поднимается по дереву в обратном порядке, где каждый раз добавляется в начало этого массива значения n-(k-1), затем n-(k-2)..., где k - глубина рекурсии, размеров в передаваемое изначальной функции, число. Пока непосредственный потомок нашей функции не вернет итоговый массив из корневой функции на последнем шаге.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Наконец то понял, как это работает, что пустой массив возвращается в самом последнем звене функции, и затем возвращается обратно, собирая на каждой вложенной функции значения от unshift, и когда возвращается обратно на базовую функцию, собирает последнюю пятерку, и уже возвращает весь массив.